# string.find function functionality in Lua

Tags: string, lua, find

Below is my piece of code

```
str = "abc@hotmailcom"
a = string.find(str , "@")
print(a)
```

*My output is 4 i.e place value of "@"*

But when I run the following piece of code

```
str = "abc@hotmailcom"
a = string.find(str , ".")
print(a)
```

*instead of outputting "nil", the program returns the value 1.*

I am new to Lua language so could anyone explain to me what is happening and how string.find() works in lua?

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a character class for all characters in lua pattern, you have to to escape it with `%`.
See [Lua Patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)

```lua
> print(string.find("abc@hotmailcom", "."))
1       1
> print(string.find("abc@hotmailcom", "%."))
nil
```

Comment: Also `string.find("abc@hotmailcom", ".",1,true)`, to avoid interpreting magic characters.